Streamlit app spams DEBUG logs despite loglevels are set correctly
I have a streamlit app. I correctly set its log level to INFO, however I get tons of debug messages like this:
[2024-07-03T09:42:03+0000 | DEBUG  |inotify_buffer      |watchdog.observers.inotify_buffer]: in-event <InotifyEvent: src_path=b'/app/streamlit/logs/myapp.log', wd=3, mask=IN_MODIFY, cookie=0, name='myapp.log'>

How do I suppress this? Setting the root level of the logger didn't change anything, and neither did setting the loglevel of inotify_buffer or watchdog.
